# What is the Unicode code for the "parallelograms" symbol?

Tags: unicode

What is the Unicode code for the parallelograms symbol?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no such character in Unicode. For practical certainty on this, use your favorite Unicode character reference (my favorites are the BabelPad editor and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm ) and search for “parallelogram”, allowing partial matches. You will only find PARALLELOGRAM and BLACK PARALLELOGRAM.

Answer (score 0):

`U+25B1`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I've already found that symbol. Is there one for "parallelograms" (with the 's' inside of it) instead of "parallelogram" (no 's')?

Comment: I don't think so. I've seen similar ones on Unix Exchange which is a part of this portal where in you can display letters as keyboard keys. This is generated via HTML (and CSS) and not via individual characters. Check this answer for an idea of what I'm talking about http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43005/17919 Check how the letters look like keyboard keys. They are wrapped in a `<kbd></kbd>` html tags.